# Why script doesn't see envvar while installing via Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, deb, environment-variables

I have a .deb package with configuration script which reads some environmental variable.

This variable is added to `/etc/environment` file, and the system was rebooted.

When I install the package from terminal the script can read the value of variable.
But when I install the package from Ubuntu Software Center the script read the empty value.

Why might this happen?

Comment: How is your script written? How it checks the variable? Does it source it?

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/environment` is only read at login so any settings there are only known by programs started from users after login.

Ubuntu Software Center uses `aptdaemon` to do the package installation. `aptdaemon` is a system service (started on demand by DBus) so it doesn't know about the settings in `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Can I somehow pass environment variable for USC?

Comment: Your package should not rely on environment variables being available, which aren't defined directly in the scripts of your package. Doing so will result in problems.

Comment: As far as I know there is no easy way to set env vars for `aptdaemon` (USC is run as user and gets the ones from `/etc/environment`). Maybe you could replace the call to `/usr/sbin/aptd` in `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.debian.apt.service` with a call to wrapper script that sets the needed env vars and then starts `/usr/sbin/aptd`.